# PHP Show other page while uploading a file

Tags: php, redirect, upload

I was wondering if it's possible to show a different page while uploading a large file.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="user.php?inh=user/uploading">
```

When I click on "submit" to send out the form and upload the file, it starts uploading immediately on the same page without any notification. So I want to redirect users to another page where they can see a loading GIF and a bit more information about the stuff they filled in, in the rest of the form.

Anyone any ideas how I can show my visitors "`user.php?inh=user/uploading`" instead of waiting to finish the upload and THEN redirect me to that page.

Comment: maybe use ajax to handle the upload...

Answer (score 0):

IMO, best plan of attack for this would be to use **AJAX** to handle the upload.

Here is a link that might be of some use: [Upload Files with AJAX Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/)